# Configure GoDaddy when hosting via custom port

Tags: nginx, http, vps, godaddy, bootstrap

I rent a VPS / seedbox that happens to offer http file hosting via nginx. Instead of renting another service to host my website, I've configured my current VPS successfully. The catch is that nginx is assigned a random port above 10000.

I rented a domain name from GoDaddy, and tried using their "forwarding with masking" functionality to point to my nginx configuration. This was the only solution I've noticed that can handle a port other than 80. This breaks my mobile (bootstrap) functionality. The viewport seems to become misunderstood.

**I need some way of hosting my website (IP:port) where the user only sees my domain**

My favorite of last resorts: `an A record from domain --> server`. This allows the user to type my domain into their browser, followed by the port `domain:port` and they will hit my server at `IP:port`. But, if they type my domain without the port, they will hit my server IP port 80, which is the manage page for the VPS service. I would hide this using the GoDaddy forwarding service, to forward all requests of the top-level domain, into the custom port: `domain --> domain:port`

This results in a link from `domain --> domain:port where domain --> IP`, which just isn't working and doesn't exactly look like it should or even could work.

*I need advice from someone who knows more about DNS and records, to tell me if there are any elegant solutions for utilizing a pretty domain name while hosting elsewhere through a custom port* or just tell me where I went wrong :)

Comment: Why isn't your web server on port 80?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the VPS service uses port 80 for its website where users can login and manage. the nginx functionality is a bit of a side service

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Is it your VPS or not?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it shares one IP over multiple virtual boxes

Comment: You need your own IP address to do what you're trying to do. Go find another VPS provider.

Comment: @MichaelHampton if that's the end-all be-all and you know it, please respond to the question with the conclusion so we can mark this question resolved